# How to convert Win Mobile 6 project into Win CE 6.0 RC2

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a Windows Mobile 6 Professional native project that runs ok on Win Mobile devices. Now I need a version that runs on Windows Embedded CE 6.0 RC2. What is the best path for this conversion? Can I just change few project settings / add new platform with configuration manager OR I have to start with new smart device project and import the existing files?

Further, I will be targeting the device which is still not delivered to me, so currently playing with Win CE image I constructed with platform builder (I tried to have very generic OS, with most default components included, of course this will change later). So now I created SDK for my OS, installed it and new smart device projects are targeting this SDK. How it goes in "real world" embedded app development, should the company deliver me SDK, BSP or something else? The real hardware will come not so soon so I need to start developing without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a new configuration to a native platform is, and always has been, a real nightmare.  Your best bet is to just create a new project and add in the source files again.  I've complained about this to the Studio for Devices team several times, but it doesn't seem to be a priority to fix.

Bear in mind that if you used anything WinMo specific, you're going to have to fix that or come up with a workaround for WinCE.

As far as targeting your hardware, you should try to generate an SDK that is as close to what your final OS image will contain as possible.  That means the same processor and hopefully the same components.  This will prevent you from using libraries or APIs that aren't available in the final OS image.

Whether you get an SDK or a BSP depends on how you've worked that out with your vendor.  If they are providing just the hardware and you have to roll the OS, then you would get a BSP.  If they are providing the hardware and the OS, then they must provide an SDK.